# How do I export text from an excel cell with alphanumeric values into another column?

Tags: string, excel, formulas

I have several cell entries in column B. They look similar to this:

```
1050670||Target Optical  4226||6132||7132
1051752||Wal-Mart Vision Ctr  305095||6132||7132
1052470||Wal-Mart Vision Ctr  301891||6132||7132
1054354||Naval Ambulatory Care Ctr||6132||7132
```

I need a formula that will extract only the text containing the name. Ideally it would look leave me with only:

```
Target Optical
Wal-Mart Vision Ctr
Wal-Mart Vision Ctr
Naval Ambulatory Care Ctr
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I did but try to use the text to columns funtion, but this did not help achieve the desired result.  I'm sure this due to a failure on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disregard the numbers within the Text pseudo-field, you will have to parse the split-out value closely for characters within ASCII 48-57.

[image: Text Only parsing]

That ugly formula in B1 is,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0, MIN(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0)))+((CODE(MID((MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0))),1))<48)+(CODE(MID(UPPER(MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(MID(A1, FIND("||", A1)+2, FIND("¶", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "||", "¶", 2))-FIND("||", A1)-2)&0))),1))>57))*1E+99,,))-1))
```

Fill down as necessary. As bad as it looks, the calculation load on a medium array formula would dwarf it but the `INDIRECT` does make it volatile so get your stripped values and Copy, Paste Special Values back to remove the formulas.

Comment: thank you very much this works as well - i really appreciate the help w/ this

Comment: @user3509034 - It is unclear to me whether you wanted the numbers within the text field excluded or not. Perhaps you should edit your question and include the numbers in the preferred sample output. e.g. *Target Optical 4226*

Comment: @pnuts - I'm busy looking up the definition of PERFECT. Perhaps it has an alternate meaning when typed in uppercase.

Comment: my apologies. for clarity - both formulas serve my needs. after closer review, the formula @jeeped provided is best. again, i really appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your entries is in B1, use the formula

```
=MID(B1,FIND("||",B1)+2,FIND("||",B1,FIND("||",B1)+2)-FIND("||",B1)-2)
```

Copy and paste as needed. Be careful about relative/absolute referencing.

Of course, there are other options with VBA, but you specifically requested a formula.

If you needed later items between "||"s, the formula that I posted could be adapted, but it could become quite cumbersome. VBA can be simpler. Or you could use

```
=MID(B1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"|",CHAR(1),(A6-1)*2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"|",CHAR(1),A6*2))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"|",CHAR(1),(A6-1)*2))-2)
```

It is cumbersome as well, but it works for "any" item number (there is an upper limit, of course; I did not test it).
This is an adaptation from [here](http://excel.tips.net/T003324_Finding_the_Nth_Occurrence_of_a_Character.html). A6 contains the item # you want to pick. In your case, it is 2. If you put three, you obtain "6132" for your first line. This formula has to be modified for suitable finding the first or last items.

**EDIT**: these formulas do not remove the numbers at the end of the target field. I missed this point, but I will leave the answer, as it may be useful for other readers. See the solution by Jeeped.

Comment: Thanks so much this was PERFECT. Exactly what I needed.  I love you guys.

Comment: @pnuts - It worked for me (I tested it prior to posting). And it worked for the OP. If you happen to find the cause, please post a comment.

Comment: @pnuts - Excel 2010. I missed removing the numbers at the end of the target field, and I think you did too. I do not understand your question.

Comment: Very useful. Particularly the second offering. +1 from here.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the below formula if you wish to. It does **not** use the **Indirect function**.

**=MID(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2),1,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ","¶",LEN(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ",""))),FIND("¶",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ","¶",LEN(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ",""))))+1,50)))=TRUE,FIND("¶",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ","¶",LEN(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2,FIND("||",A1,FIND("||",A1,1)+2)-FIND("||",A1,1)-2)," ",""))))-1,50))**